# Corrupting a database backup to fail CHECKSUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

I'm currently setting up the monitoring for some SQL servers running on windows and I want to test if it picks up any errors that occur when backups fail. I'm using the CHECKSUM option for backup validation.
Is it possible to corrupt the backup in a way so that the CHECKSUM validation fails?

Comment: Edit the file, delete some bytes from the end or replace it with another one, eg rename a text file to `something.bak`

Answer (score 0):

`CHECKSUM` verifies the file is not corrupt in the *same* RESTORE or BACKUP command; can also be set at a database-level so it always runs a self-check. I don't know of a way to intentionally cause this to fail *during* a BACKUP command, unless you're corrupting it on the I/O level outside of SQL Server.

`RESTORE HEADERONLY` verifies the file can be restored completely; this can be performed any time after the backup has completed. Essentially, fake-attempts a full restore to ensure the file is a legit backup. [More info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).